# Issue with Fetching Date using SYSDATE?

Tags: sql, oracle, sysdate

I have a table structure having a EMP_DATE column as below

```
 ID       EMP_DATE
----    -----------
5400     14-FEB-2012
```

and i have inserted records into the table as below

```
INSERT INTO TEST_DATE VALUES(5400,SYSDATE);
```

After inserting records while i am trying to fetch the records of those who has `EMP_DATE`
as `SYSDATE` its giving no rows selected.
For time being let the `SYSDATE` be '01-JUL-2012`

```
 SELECT * FROM TEST_DATE WHERE EMP_DATE = SYSDATE;
                (OR)
 SELECT * FROM TESt_DATE WHERE EMP_DATE = '01-JUL-2012';
```

i was not able figure out any solution .
Any suggestions would be helpful .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is that a date includes hours, minutes and seconds, which you're not allowing for. If you want everything for a single day you can use the [`trunc`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php) function in order to get this:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_DATE WHERE trunc(EMP_DATE) = trunc(SYSDATE);
```

By default `trunc` removes the time portion of a date, when operating on a date column. I would normally recommend a functional index on `trunc(emp_date)` in order to optimize this query. Something like:

```
create index i_test_date on test_date(trunc(emp_date));
```

I've built a little [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/679ee/1) to demonstrate this.

There is an additional problem; though Oracle does support ANSI date literals your second query is wrong. *Always*, explicitly convert to a string to a date using the [`to_date`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function.

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_DATE WHERE EMP_DATE = to_date('01-07-2012','dd-mm-yyyy');
```

I've used the `mm` [datetime format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) instead of `mon` as there's no guarantee that `JUL` will always mean July; it depends on your NLS parameters, what "date language" your particular database or session is using. A datetime format model is how you tell the database the format of whatever string you're passing it to be converted into a date.

---

If you're interested the ANSI syntax for your second query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM TESt_DATE WHERE trunc(EMP_DATE) = DATE '2012-07-01'
```

It must be in this format (YYYY-MM-DD) to work.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your suggestion !!
So when ever i insert the date using SYSDATE it will store accordingly with date and time .

and to fetch the same do i need to trunc the date to get the result ?

Comment: @Aspirant, if you want _every_ result for that day, yes. Don't forget that `sysdate` is constantly changing so as soon as you've inserted a record and try to select it, `sysdate` will have "ticked" on a few seconds and the date will not be _exactly_ the same. Have a play around and see for yourself :-)